# Blocking links in robots but inluding sitemap

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt, nofollow

Can I for example, include

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

in the robots and then include all of the links i want including the home page in the sitemap
and multiple other sitemaps and have them be indexed?
Does that work?

I have noticed one of our competitors uses robots to disallow links, and also uses rel=nofollow on those exact same links, but uses extensive sitemaps to make up for it and they are indexed. I have noticed that this method is better for certain sites which are link heavy and require specific order.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Pages restricted by *robots.txt* won't be indexed at all. According to Google Webmaster Tools:

> If your site has content you don't want Google or other search engines to access, use a robots.txt file to specify how search engines should crawl your site's content.

Including such URLs to *sitemap.xml* won't affect on indexing also.